# In C#, retrieving text data that has been stored in a form object's tag

Tags: c#

I've used basic of various sorts for years. One trick that I have frequently employed with Visual Basic is the following: when I wanted to associate invisible text with a form control object -- a button, label, and (particularly) a picturebox -- I have stored useful text in the object's tag. (This is particularly utilitarian with picturboxes since they don't carry a text attribute.)

In any case, you can do the following in Visual Basic with no difficulty:

```
textbox1.tag = "ID of whatever sort"
```

Later you can retrieve the data by assigning the .tag content to a string variable, or revealing it in the .text property.

So:

```
textbox1.text = textbox1.tag
```

presents no difficulty and raises no error.

This can't be done in C#. At least not directly. Even though you can directly assign text to a tag, you can't retrieve it as text.

I believe this is because C# regards .Tag property's content as an object. However, presumably, so does Visual Basic, but it still allows the transfer without objection.

So my request: can any of you veteran C# masters show me precisely how I can get text assigned to a .Tag and into .Text?

Comment: Its not boxing :P as string is a reference type

Comment: @TheGeneral Doh. Yes. Right you are :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast it

```
textbox1.text = (string)textbox1.tag
```

Basically all types inherit from `object`, since string is a reference type when storing it as an `object` its just storing it as its most fundamental base type. For value types, this process is known as boxing. You can read about them both below

[object (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/object)

> The object type is an alias for Object in .NET. In the unified type
>   system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types
>   and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object. You can
>   assign values of any type to variables of type object. When a variable
>   of a value type is converted to object, it is said to be boxed. When a
>   variable of type object is converted to a value type, it is said to be
>   unboxed. For more information, see Boxing and Unboxing.

[Value Types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)

> The value types consist of two main categories:
>
> - Structs
> - Enumerations
>
> Structs fall into these categories:
>
> - Numeric types
>
>   - Integral types
>   - Floating-point types
> - bool
> - User defined structs.

[Reference types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types.
>   Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects),
>   while variables of value types directly contain their data. With
>   reference types, two variables can reference the same object;
>   therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced
>   by the other variable. With value types, each variable has its own
>   copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one
>   variable to affect the other (except in the case of in, ref and out
>   parameter variables; see in, ref and out parameter modifier)

[Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR
>   boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and
>   stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from
>   the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of
>   boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system
>   in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

Comment: Just cast it

textbox1.text = (string)textbox1.tag

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks to all who chimed in, but that one line provided the methodology I was looking for. The theory is fascinating, but the terminology about boxing and unboxing is a bit bewildering. Later, when I know more about C# it might be of more use. In the meantime, thanks to TheGeneral for the concise 'how to'. :-)